# How do I connect TV cables to this signal booster unit?

Tags: tv-antenna, coaxial-cable

I am trying to connect some coaxial cables to a antenna amplifier unit. I have 3 cables going to various TV plugs, and a single cable connected to an antenna. All cables are terminated with the connector shown below.

[image]

The booster unit is the one below. It doesn't allow me to simply screw the connector in place, so what connectors would I need to buy (and what tools - I've seen mention of crimpers and compression tools) to connect up the 4 cables?

The antenna input also has a different socket type than the TV outputs, even though all my connectors are the same, so I presume this would need another connection type?

[image]

Thanks for any details you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 3):

The amplifier appears to have Belling-Lee connectors ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_aerial_plug)) while the cables look like they have "F" connectors
 ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_connector)). Assuming you are in Europe, you should be able to find adapters. If you are in the USA, BL adapters are hard to find but I've gotten them from Radio Shack in the past.

[image]

Also called PAL or European to F Adapter

Comment: Agreed that this is almost certainly a Belling-Lee amplifier. I can't imagine anything like this that would have been sold in the USA that would have a 230V power supply. Both sides of the connection can also be seen - 4 males for the TVs, 1 female for the antenna.

Comment: And the inputs and outputs are inherently defined by the pin and socket design so you can't be accidentally plugging the wrong thing into the wrong thing like you could with BNC and F connectors.

Comment: @Comintern - good catch on the power rating.  I missed it.

Comment: Thanks - you are correct that the amplifier was bought in France for French cabling

Comment: @DoxyLover - You're welcome!